# What is the most efficient std algorithm to find the closest range of an input number in a std::map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdmap

My data will be stored in a map of integer and integer
The key is the start_range of any number
The value is the end_range

e.g.  My map will look like this :

```
  std::map<int,int> mymap;
  mymap[100]=200;
  mymap[1000]=2000;
  mymap[2000]=2500;
  mymap[3000]=4000;
  mymap[5000]=5100;
```

Now, if my input number is 150, the algorithm should return an iterator to mymap[100]. 
But, the range check logic with the value of output (i.e iterator->second) shall be done separately to verify if it falls in the correct range.

for input number 4500, it may return mymap[5000], but the range check logic should fail as it is from 5000 to 5100.
Please NOTE that there is no OVERLAP of ranges in the map.

Answer (score 5):

You have `std::lower_bound` to find the lowest item which doesn't meet your search value.

```
auto it = mymap.lower_bound( value );
```

From [cplusplus map::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/)

> A similar member function, upper_bound, has the same behavior as lower_bound, except in the case that the map contains an element with a key equivalent to k: In this case, lower_bound returns an iterator pointing to that element, whereas upper_bound returns an iterator pointing to the next element.

So `lower_bound` returns the first value which is not less than the search.  This means that for the preceding value, you would need `lower_bound - 1`, but only in the case where `lower_bound != begin()`

```
auto it = mymap.lower_bound( value );
if( it->first != value && it != mymap.begin() ) {
    it --;
}
```

or to use `upper_bound`

```
auto it = mymap.upper_bound( value );
if( it != mymap.begin() ) {
    it --;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*upper_bound* looks for the key *greater than* (**>**) supplied key or stops at the end of the map.

*lower_bound* looks for the key *greater than or equal to* (**>=**) supplied key or stops at the end of the map

Given below is the code to find the closest range of input number: [Demo](http://ideone.com/S3dkGi)

```
typedef std::map<int,int>::iterator Iter;

Iter getIterator(std::map<int,int> &m, int val) {
    Iter lb = m.upper_bound(val);
    if(lb == m.begin()) {
        return m.end();
    }
    Iter it = std::prev(lb);
    if(it->first <= val && val <= it->second ) {
        return it;
    }
    else{
        return m.end();
    }
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::map<int,int> mymap;
    mymap[100]=200;
    mymap[1000]=2000;
    mymap[2000]=2500;
    mymap[3000]=4000;
    mymap[5000]=5100;

    int a[4]{4500, 4000, 150, 0};
    for(int x : a){
        Iter it = getIterator(mymap, x);
        if(it != mymap.end()){
            cout << "Value " << x << " : Found in range: " << it->first << ", " << it->second <<endl;
        }else{
            cout << "Value " << x << " : NOT FOUND!" <<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```